# Main linked shared library is a symlink?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build `libxvidcore` from source using the tarball and working off of the [RPM specfile provided in RPMFusion](http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/releases/22/Everything/source/SRPMS/repoview/xvidcore.html). I have my reasons for repackaging this.

```
%global _hardened_build 1
# can't seem to find debug info for now
%global debug_package %{nil}

%define package_name libxvidcore
%define package_version 1.3.4
%define package_release 1

Name: %{package_name}
Summary: A video decoder and encoder library aimed at providing the best compression efficiency and picture quality possible.
Version: %{package_version}
Release: %{package_release}%{?dist}
License: GPL
Source: http://downloads.xvid.org/downloads/xvidcore-%{package_version}.tar.bz2

%ifarch %{ix86} x86_64
BuildRequires: nasm
%endif

%description
A video decoder and encoder library aimed at providing the best compression efficiency and picture quality possible.

%prep

%setup -n xvidcore

%build
cd build/generic
%configure

make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
make -C build/generic install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%{_libdir}/libxvidcore.so.4
%{_libdir}/libxvidcore.so.4.3

%post -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -p /sbin/ldconfig

%package devel
Summary: libxvidcore-devel
Requires: libxvidcore = %{package_version}
%description devel
libxvidcore-devel
%files devel
%{_includedir}/xvid.h
%{_libdir}/libxvidcore.so
%exclude %{_libdir}/libxvidcore.a
```

A really strange things happens with the shared libraries. The files provided by `libxvidcore` are:

```
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4 -> /usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4.3
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4.3
```

The `libxvidcore-devel` package depends on `libxvidcore`. However, I can't install `libxvidcore-devel` due to the following error:

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh RPMS/x86_64/libxvidcore-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm \
                RPMS/x86_64/libxvidcore-devel-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit) is needed by libxvidcore-devel-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64
```

This shared library (`libxvidcore.so.4`) as pointed out above, is a symlink to `libxvidcore.so.4.3`, which is the real ELF shared library. Since I'm not defining how this build runs, I'm not sure how to work around this.

Here's the layout of the packages:

```
$ rpm -qp --provides --fileprovide RPMS/x86_64/libxvidcore-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm
libxvidcore = 1.3.4-1.fc23
libxvidcore(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.fc23
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4.3
$ rpm -qp --provides --fileprovide RPMS/x86_64/libxvidcore-devel-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm
libxvidcore-devel = 1.3.4-1.fc23
libxvidcore-devel(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.fc23
/usr/include/xvid.h
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so
```

For sanity's sake, here's the info on the shared library as reported by `file`:

```
$ file /usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4{,.3}
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4:   symbolic link to libxvidcore.so.4.3
/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=86c2c379f2ca0dc2f3d3f1306c55de29b1d76738, not stripped
```

Here's some more info on the libxvidcore package:

```
$ rpm -qi --qf 'Arch : %{arch}\n' --provides libxvidcore
Name        : libxvidcore
Version     : 1.3.4
Release     : 1.fc23
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Mon 25 Jan 2016 01:28:08 AM UTC
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 2697952
License     : GPL
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : libxvidcore-1.3.4-1.fc23.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 25 Jan 2016 01:27:50 AM UTC
Build Host  : fedora23
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Summary     : A video decoder and encoder library aimed at providing the best compression efficiency and picture quality possible.
Description :
A video decoder and encoder library aimed at providing the best compression efficiency and picture quality possible.
Arch : x86_64
libxvidcore = 1.3.4-1.fc23
libxvidcore(x86-64) = 1.3.4-1.fc23
```

Is there a way for me to deal with the weird symlink properly?

Comment: Is `libxvidcore-devel-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64` your package? Is `libxvidcore-devel-1.3.4-1.fc23.x86_64` already installed on your system for some reason? What does `rpm -qp --provides $your_vidcore_package` output?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have updated the question with output from your commands.

Comment: Those aren't your packages though. Those are the official Fedora 23 packages aren't they? Why are you looking at those? Why are those installed? I thought the whole point here was to build your own packages? If that's what you want then you don't want the stock packages installed (though this may cause problems as your packages may or may not satisfy other official packages requirements).

Comment: @EtanReisner These _are_ my packages, I built them with my own spec file. I'm rebuilding them because RPMFusion doesn't have an up-to-date version. In regular Fedora 23, these packages aren't available.

Comment: You somehow built a 32bit package (or overrode the detection somehow). What does `file` say about the `/usr/lib64/libxvidcore.so.4.3` file in your main package? Do you have the compilation/linking commands/output from the package build?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have updated the question with the requested information. It's a 64-bit ELF file, somehow the detection is failing or something.

Comment: You have your `libxvidcore` package installed already? The problem is just with installing the `libxvidcore-devel` package then? What does `rpm -qi --qf 'Arch        : %{arch}\n' --provides libxvidcore` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have updated the question with the output. It shows the arch as being x86_64. Should I just give you my spec file and the source tarball?

Comment: I don't have a fedora 23 system to try this on. Did you modify the spec file from what you included in your question? The package is clearly being built on an x86_64 machine but the libraries aren't being detected as such correctly. Do you have the build logs?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have shipped my configuration using a Vagrant box for the builds here: https://github.com/rfkrocktk/libxvidcore-rpm-demo . You can check out the project, `vagrant up fedora23` and use `rpmbuild` to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: I figured out the problem but not why it is happening. The problem is that rpm is "smart". It only scans libraries with execute permissions for library provides. For some reason the xvidcore build is broken and doesn't create the library with execute permissions. Fix that (as I did in a quick test with `chmod` in the `%install` section and you get `libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit)` in the `--requires` output as expected. I don't know why the build wouldn't be doing that by itself though. It feels like it should be. (Also this took me **way** too long to notice when I was poking at it.)

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you so much, please submit as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. I didn't know shared libraries needed the execute bit.

Comment: I don't know that they actually have to have it to function (on all systems) but they do (as far as I know) traditionally have it set and rpm pays attention to that. This is part of why I'm surprised that the xvidcore build isn't doing this "correctly" in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that rpm is "smart". It only scans libraries with execute permissions for library provides during the `rpmbuild` process.

For some reason the xvidcore build is broken (in this respect) and isn't installing the library with execute permissions.

Fix that (as I did in a quick test with a call to `chmod` in the `%install` section but you should probably look for a better solution) and you get `libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit)` in the `--requires` output as expected.

I don't know why the build wouldn't be doing that by itself though; I think it should be.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help debugging this!

Answer (score -1):

It might help to first summarize the customary organization of a library 'base' package and the corresponding library 'base'-devel package:

```
file           package      function
-------------------------------------------------------------
libmy.so.x.y      my        actual implementation
libmy.so.x        my        SONAME reference for dynamic linking
                            (relative symlink to mylib.so.x.y)
libmy.so          my-devel  linker library
                            (relative symlink to mylib.so.x)
mylib.h           my-devel  source header
```

Because the linker library is a symlink to the SONAME library, it is a natural consequence that the 'base'-devel package requires the 'base' package.  I think your libxvidcore-devel package is behaving as expected.  When both packages are in a Yum repository and the 'base'-devel package is requested, Yum will resolve the requirements and install both.

For development work, if you are using 'rpm' commands directly to install packages, you simply need to specify both in your installation command:

```
rpm -i <base> <base>-devel
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What you have described above is exactly the case. I have updated my question with additional information. I cannot install the package with `rpm -ivh libxvidcore-*.rpm`.